# How to find and store same document from 2 mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

My program generate 2 collection everyday in my database. Each day I have to compare these 2 collection and have to find out whether some specific elements of the documents are same in both the collection. If they are same I have to store the document somewhere.

**Note:** *Each collection have 94.6k documents. Each document contains these columns or elements –
_id(which is different all the time), studentName, timeOfEntry, timeOfExit, section, class.*

*I also have one more collection named as names which. contains name of all students(which are unique) *

I have to find out which document in the 2 collection have same value for studentName, timeOfEntry and timeOfExit.
How can I achieve this?

##### Example:

Like in collection1 -- a document contain the value of student:"Isha" ,entryTime:5pm and exitTime: 7pm.

collection 2 also contain a document with these values.

**My approach:**
** I was trying to create a function in springboot java where --
function(){
compare the 2 collection
}**

Comment: If it's just ~500 docs, I'd read both collections in full and compare elements in the app.

Comment: Sorry -- 1 collection have 94.6k document

Comment: those 2 collections, can have also duplicates on those fields(i mean in the same collection)? also there is possibility to have multiple duplicates from the 2 collections, you want to save all those documents?

Comment: No, a collection does not contain duplicate documents and there is no multiple duplicate from 2 collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- union the 2 collections
- group by the 3 fields, and count the occurrences
- keep only the duplicates (count>1)
- fix the structure of the document
- `$out` to write to the new collection

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70578541-m)

```js
coll1.aggregate(
[{"$unionWith":{"coll":"coll2"}},
 {"$group":
  {"_id":
   {"studentName":"$studentName",
    "timeOfEntry":"$timeOfEntry",
    "timeOfExit":"$timeOfExit"},
   "count":{"$sum":1},
   "doc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$match":{"$expr":{"$gt":["$count", 1]}}},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$doc"}}
 {"$out": "newCollectionWithDuplicates"}])
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Takis. Just want to ask one more question what if we don't want to aggregate the report. Because there are 99.6k documents in each collection. Can't we do it in a manner where in springboot java we can create a method which will find the same documents with required fields .

Comment: if the data are in the database, you cant find duplicates with another way expect to aggregate(sending them to the app and do it on java will be slow and possible memory problems if more data), but i am not sure i understand the question, i don't use springboot java but i guess you can aggregate with their query builder.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your support. I really appreciate it. Actually my senior asked me to mainly create a function. I'm working on springboot java

Comment: i dont know but you can create a function that sends this query, in all cases your function will query the database

Comment: Hey Takis.. please help.. I'm not getting any output on using the above query.

Comment: can you give an example of data that didn't work? You have to see how to use `$out` with your driver, for example in Java its not a stage in the pipeline, its a method we call on the cursor.

Comment: I haven't used this query in java. I have simply used this in mongoDb Compass terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240760/discussion-between-takis-and-vartika-malguri).